# Avoid focus to go beyond a particular button using tab button

Tags: javascript, html

Lets take a scenario, where in I have a series of buttons `btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3`...

I kept pressing 'tab' key and my focus is on `btn2`. Now I want to avoid `btn3` or any other beyond `btn2` not to get focus on tab key press.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of the tab key can be changed with the tabindex attribute. It is the order the elements will have the focus.

With

```
    <button id="1" tabindex="-1">Some content</button>
```

you should prevent the focus to be on your button.

or like this:

```
 $(".btnclass").attr("tabindex", "-1");
```

check this:http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TABINDEX.html

Comment: In this case I will have to add tabindex for all the buttons except btn1 and btn2... but why cant we play with btn2 and avoid tab key press on that button?

Comment: try to get something from link if you don't want this.do one thing give a separate class to all other button and apply tabindex -1 through jQuery.